# BeautifulSoup Get a link's content/text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
URL = "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=1.0"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links_with_text = []


for random in soup.find_all("span", attrs={"id": re.compile("^msg")}):
    for b in random.find_all('a', href=True):
          print(b['href'])
```

The above code works just fine. I can get all the topics from the first page, but the problem lays in getting the topics names. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which libraries are you using apart from requests and bs4?

Comment: re (regex) and pprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work:

```py
URL = "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=1.0"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links_with_text = []

for random in soup.find_all("span", attrs={"id": re.compile("^msg")}):
    for b in random.find_all('a', href=True):
          print(b['href'])
          print(b.string)
```

Sample output:

```
...
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5320354.0
Craig Wright's Latest Escapade -- Give me the bitcoins I stole from Mt. Gox!
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5233719.0
Opera now lets US users buy crypto with Apple Pay or debit card
...
```

Comment: It did thanks. I'm wondering, how come Visual studio is not displaying the methods, and functions I could call on 'b'?

Comment: I use VS Code as well, and it is probably because it could not find the type of the variable. Without a type, it cannot make any recommendations. But I could be wrong here